# Recover and/or ignore fatal error when host unreachable

Tags: ansible

How can I catch a fatal unreachable host error:

```
fatal: [x.x.x.x]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: xxxx@x.x.x.x.: Permission denied (publickey).", "unreachable": true}
```

It appears that ignore_errors: yes does not work, and "rescue" won't either.

Using Ansible 2.8.3

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved it:

```
ignore_unreachable: yes
```

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html